# DirectXMath vector operations precision

Tags: c++, xna, directx, direct3d, directx-11

I'm having strange results of XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors function. Consider this code:

```
float angle = XMConvertToDegrees(XMVectorGetX(
        XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors(GMathFV(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f)), 
        GMathFV(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 200.0f, 0.0f)))));
```

It's looking for angle between two 3D vectors, described by XMFLOAT3 structures. GMathFV is user-defined function which converts XMFLOAT3 to XMVECTOR as follows:

```
inline XMVECTOR GMathFV(XMFLOAT3& val)
{
    return XMLoadFloat3(&val);    
}
```

Everything else is directxmath.h library. Here everything is fine and result angle is 0.00000 just as expected.

But for other vectors with negative y-axis value, for example:

```
float angle = XMConvertToDegrees(XMVectorGetX(
        XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors(GMathFV(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f)), 
        GMathFV(XMFLOAT3(0.0f, -99.0f, 0.0f)))));
```

Result is 0.0197823402, which I can hardly call a zero angle.

Please someone help me figure out the problem. Is it negative number precision, too close vector coordinates or maybe something else?

UPD: Amazing, but it gives 0.0197823402 for `a(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f) x b(0.0f, 99.0f, 0.0f)`, but 0.000000 for `a(0.0f, 101.0f, 0.0f) x b(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f)`

Comment: Does the DirectXMath use radians or degrees?

Comment: @Xathereal it uses radians.

Comment: DirectX sets a low-precision FPU flag by default, which may cause the issues you're seeing. To tell it to preserve the FPU flags inside DX calls, call `CreateDevice` with `D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE` in the behaviour field, or for .Net use [`CreateFlags.FpuPreserve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms859062.aspx).  Does that help? Watch out for your FPU flags causing exceptions in some circumstances.

Comment: @DavidM thanks for response. It looks like D3D11 device is already set for double precision as there is no way to set this flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectXMath is designed for 32bit floating point math.  You're seeing [floating point error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) escalation.  Here's the definition of XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors.

```
inline XMVECTOR XM_CALLCONV XMVector3AngleBetweenVectors(FXMVECTOR V1, FXMVECTOR V2)
{
    XMVECTOR L1 = XMVector3ReciprocalLength(V1);
    XMVECTOR L2 = XMVector3ReciprocalLength(V2);

    XMVECTOR Dot = XMVector3Dot(V1, V2);

    L1 = XMVectorMultiply(L1, L2);

    XMVECTOR CosAngle = XMVectorMultiply(Dot, L1);
    CosAngle = XMVectorClamp(CosAngle, g_XMNegativeOne.v, g_XMOne.v);

    return XMVectorACos(CosAngle);
}
```

In your first example CosAngle equals 1.000000000

In your second example CosAngle equals 0.999999940

XMVectorACos(0.999999940) = 0.000345266977

This large error comes from a polynomial approximation of ACos.  In general you should avoid trigonometric inverses whenever possible.  They are slow and noisy.  Here's the definition so you can get an idea of its size.

```
inline XMVECTOR XM_CALLCONV XMVectorACos (FXMVECTOR V)
{
    __m128 nonnegative = _mm_cmpge_ps(V, g_XMZero);
    __m128 mvalue = _mm_sub_ps(g_XMZero, V);
    __m128 x = _mm_max_ps(V, mvalue);  // |V|

    // Compute (1-|V|), clamp to zero to avoid sqrt of negative number.
    __m128 oneMValue = _mm_sub_ps(g_XMOne, x);
    __m128 clampOneMValue = _mm_max_ps(g_XMZero, oneMValue);
    __m128 root = _mm_sqrt_ps(clampOneMValue);  // sqrt(1-|V|)

    // Compute polynomial approximation
    const XMVECTOR AC1 = g_XMArcCoefficients1;
    XMVECTOR vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3) );
    __m128 t0 = _mm_mul_ps(vConstants, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC1, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    const XMVECTOR AC0 = g_XMArcCoefficients0;
    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC0, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC0, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC0, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, x);

    vConstants = XM_PERMUTE_PS( AC0, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0) );
    t0 = _mm_add_ps(t0, vConstants);
    t0 = _mm_mul_ps(t0, root);

    __m128 t1 = _mm_sub_ps(g_XMPi, t0);
    t0 = _mm_and_ps(nonnegative, t0);
    t1 = _mm_andnot_ps(nonnegative, t1);
    t0 = _mm_or_ps(t0, t1);
    return t0;
}
```